# use string escape utility function with using Apache common library (StringEscapeUtils)

Tags: java, stringescapeutils

I want to know if there is any other way to output the same results without using Apache common Library. I did this way but i need to know how to do it without any external imports. 
Thanks a lot ahead.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils;
public class Solution
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String path="\"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0\\bin\"";
        String pathJava = StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(path);
        System.out.println("It's Window path: "+ path);
        System.out.println("It's java path: "+pathJava);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not checkout the original source [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.java#StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava%28java.lang.String%29) to understand how apache's `StringEscapeUtils` does it?

Comment: @Karkool Remembering of course to respect the copyright and licensing of the original... ;-)